# Payfort Start IOS SDK

Tags: ios, swift, payfort

I am using Payfort Start IOS SDK and now I come to know that Payfort is shut down its start SDK. There is any solution to overcome this situation?

Anybody know what kind of changes is done in new Payfort SDK so that I can implement easily. Here is my code which I am using in start SDK to create token.

```
var card: StartCard? {    
        var card: StartCard?    
        var errorString: String?    

        do {    
            let cardholder = textFieldName?.text ?? ""    
            let number = textFieldCardNumber?.text ?? ""    
            let cvc = textFieldCVV?.text ?? ""    
            let month = Int(self.month ) ??    
            let year = Int("20\(self.year )") ??    
            card = try StartCard(cardholder: cardholder, number: number, cvc: cvc, expirationMonth: month, expirationYear: year)    

        }    
        catch let error as NSError {    
            if let errors = error.userInfo[StartCardErrorKeyValues] as? [String] {    
                errorString = "The following fields are invalid:"    
                errors.forEach { errorString = "\(errorString ?? "")\n\($0)" }    
            }    
            else {    
                errorString = "Unknown error occured"    
            }    
        }    
        catch {    
            errorString = "Unknown error occured"    
        }

        if errorString != "" && errorString != nil{    
            delegate?.error(messgae: errorString ?? "")    
        }    
        return card
    }

func createToken(cell:NewCardTableViewCell){    
        let replacedString = cell.textFieldExpiryOn.text?.replace("/", replacement: "")    
        cell.month  = (replacedString?.substr(, length: 2)) ?? ""    
        cell.year = (replacedString?.substr(2, length: 2)) ?? ""    
        guard let card = cell.card else {    
            return    
        }    
        self.showLoader()    
        self.perform(#selector(self.hideLoader), with: nil, afterDelay: 60)
        start.createToken(for: card, amount: Int(paidAmount), currency: currency, successBlock: { token in    
            self.makePayment(token:token.tokenId)    
        }, errorBlock: { error in    
            self.showAlert(message: "Error occured:\n\(error.localizedDescription)")    
            self.hideLoader()    
        }, cancel: {    
            self.showAlert(message: "Cancelled")    
            self.hideLoader()    
        })    
    }    
}
```